# How to integrate Azure AD B2C with React Native

Tags: react-native, azure-ad-b2c

I want to use Azure AD B2C to use their existing functionality to login, signup, etc
However I am having problems finding updated examples or libraries

I found:

```
https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal
https://github.com/GSingh01/ad-b2c-react-native
https://github.com/michaelburch/react-native-aad-b2c-sample
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-azure-auth
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/tree/master/apps/mobile-react-native-ios-android-appauth
https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth
```

But all of them are outdated and the examples provided on them, are not working.
I did not find documentation on Microsoft.
I already have everything on the Azure side, just need to know how to integrate it and use it on the react native side

Answer (score 0):

Integrating Azure AD B2C with React Native can be a bit challenging, especially when many of the available libraries and examples are outdated. However, I'll guide you through a general approach to achieve this integration:

1. Use a Recent Library
   While many libraries are outdated, react-native-app-auth is one of the more maintained ones. Even if the specific Azure AD B2C examples are outdated, the core functionality of the library should still work with the latest React Native versions.
2. Configuration
   Before diving into code, ensure you have the following details from your Azure AD B2C setup:

- Application (client) ID
- Redirect URI  Tenant ID or domain name
- Policy names (e.g., B2C_1_signupsignin)

3. Integration with react-native-app-auth

```js
import { authorize } from 'react-native-app-auth';
    
const config = {
  clientId: 'YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID',
  redirectUrl: 'YOUR_REDIRECT_URI',
  issuer: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/YOUR_TENANT_ID/v2.0',
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access'],
  serviceConfiguration: {
    authorizationEndpoint: 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.b2clogin.com/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=YOUR_POLICY_NAME',
    tokenEndpoint: 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.b2clogin.com/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=YOUR_POLICY_NAME',
  },
};
    
const result = await authorize(config);
```

Hope this helps you integrate Azure AD B2C with your React Native app!

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT